# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined, kendo widgets not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement few KendoUI web widgets over of my page, but the widgets are not working as expected and having following issues:

1. `Editor` initializes ok, but have few issues like when you hover
   over an options it highlights but when you move away it should get
   back to normal which it doesn’t
2. If I refresh page a couple of times
   than some time `Editor` initializes fine but some time it doesn’t
3. Other widgets `kendoDatePicker();` and `kendoDropDownList();` are
   not even initializing
4. My JQ Form Validation is also not working on this page

Furthermore in chrome console I have following error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined` on line # 23679 of `kendo.web.js` which states this:

```
if (value !== DropDownList.fn.value.call(that)) {
            that.text(that.options.title);
            that._current.removeClass("k-state-selected");//This is line # 23679
            that.current(null);
            that._oldIndex = that.selectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

I have following scripts included on page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kndu/kendo.web.js"></script>
…
….

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#editor").kendoEditor({
            tools: [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull", "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                "formatBlock",
                "createLink",
                "unlink",
                "insertImage",
                "insertHtml",
                "viewHtml",
                {
                    name: "customTool",
                    tooltip: "Format as Code",
                    exec: function (e) {
                        var editor = $(this).data("kendoEditor");
                        editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: "<pre>" });
                    }
                }],

        });
        $("#date").kendoDatePicker();
        $("#categry").kendoDropDownList();


        $("#newpost").validate({
            rules: {
                ttle: {
                    maxlength: 150,
                    required: true,
                    onlyChars: true
                },
                smmry: {
                    maxlength: 250,
                    required: true
                },
                editor: {
                    maxlength: 35,
                    required: true
                },
                categry: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $.validator.addMethod('onlyChars', function (value) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid name with only alphabets');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

About `insertHTML` documentation says in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#configuration-tools):

> the insertHtml tool requires a collection of text-value pairs. A
>   separator may be included multiple times.

So you should have something like:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
        ...
        "insertHtml",
        ...
    ],
    insertHtml: [
        { text: "label 1", value: "<p>snippet 1</p>" },
        { text: "label 2", value: "<p>snippet 2</p>" }
    ]
});
```